# Can I make events propagate between originator and descendants?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom, browser

I know if I have an element fire an event, it'll propagate up to the root, then back down to the originating element.  Basically, all the ancestors get notified.  But I would like to notify all the descendants.  Can I do that?

Thanks, Rick

Comment: It's not designed that way, but there may be workarounds. Do you have a specific example?

Comment: The primary use is for layout.  If someone resizes an outer div, I want all the child divs to know that they have more or less room.

Comment: That sounds like a job for CSS, to me.

Comment: Yes you can. Can you provide an example of code where you might use this?

Comment: I am using jquery ui's resizable "widget" (behavior) to move a sash and resize a panel.  The div contains two panels.  When I make the resizable panel bigger, naturally the other panel gets smaller.  I want to tell its children that they may need to rearrange themselves.  I'll try to make a jsfiddle tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, my code might have some errors, but here it is:

```
elem = document.querySelectorAll('#my-element')[0];

function callClickOnDescendants(element, event){
  for (var i = 0, len = element.children.length; i < len; i++){
    element.children[i].onclick.call(element.children[i], event);
    callClickOnDescendants(element.children[i], event);
  }
}

elem.onclick = function(event){
  callClickOnDescendants(elem, event);
}
```

If you wait before downvoting, I'll be able to test in a jsfiddle.
**EDIT**
It works, [jsfiddle proof](http://jsfiddle.net/theonlygusti/rqqjp256/)

Comment: Hi, Gusti.  I think I get it.  I can call the event handler myself on each child.  I see how you have recursively gone all the way down the tree.  Thanks!  I think I can use this.